# JPQL query for many-to-many join table

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, jpql

I have 2 Entities User and AccountBase with a many-to-many relationship.
I need to select all AccountBase objects with a selected User ID from the join table.
I have tried some join queries but don't work.

```
    @Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_TYPE", length = 1)
    public abstract class AccountBase extends ModelBase {

        protected double balance;
        protected List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
@Table(name = "USER_ACCOUNT")
public class User extends ModelBase implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected String name;
    protected List<AccountBase> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<>();

// bi-directional many-to-many association to AccountBase
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ACCOUNT_ACCOUNT", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID") })
    public List<AccountBase> getBankAccounts() {
        return this.bankAccounts;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Join the user entity from the account base

```
select account from AccountBase account join account.users user where user.id=?
```

Comment: I have tried this one before but it didn't work, this is what i get.
`org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList[0]->com.algonquincollege.cst8277.models.User["bankAccounts"]->org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList[0]->com.algonquincollege.cst8277.models.InvestmentAccount["users"])`

InvestmentAccount extends from AccountBase.

Comment: This is a different error. You have an infinite loop when you're mapping to json, put @JsonIgnore before the users in Account or before bancAccounts in User

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem by adding @JsonIgnoreProperties in both entities.